# Problems Installing Tensor Flow Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to get tensorflow to work on my Windows 10 machine. 
I have Cude 8 and CuDNN 5.1 installed and added to the `%path%`.
Installed Python 3.5.4 then proceeded to install TensorFlow by executing 
`pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-GPU`. The computer is running a GeForce 1060.

Here is what I get when I try to import TensorFlow:

> import tensorflow as tf
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site->packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in >swig_import_helper
>      return importlib.import_module(mname)
>    File >"C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib__init__.p>y", line 126, in import_module
>      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>    File "", line 985, in _gcd_import
>    File "", line 968, in _find_and_load
>    File "", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>    File "", line 666, in _load_unlocked
>    File "", line 577, in module_from_spec
>    File "", line 938, in create_module
>    File "", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site->packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in 
>      from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site->packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in 
>      _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site->packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in >swig_import_helper
>      return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
>    File >"C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib__init__.p>y", line 126, in import_module
>      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>   ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 1, in 
>    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site->packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
>      from tensorflow.python import *
>    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site->packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
>      from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site->packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in 
>      raise ImportError(msg)
>   ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site->packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in >swig_import_helper
>      return importlib.import_module(mname)
>    File >"C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib__init__.p>y", line 126, in import_module
>      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>    File "", line 985, in _gcd_import
>    File "", line 968, in _find_and_load
>    File "", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>    File "", line 666, in _load_unlocked
>    File "", line 577, in module_from_spec
>    File "", line 938, in create_module
>    File "", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site->packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in 
>      from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site->packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in 
>      _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site->packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in >swig_import_helper
>      return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
>    File >"C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib__init__.p>y", line 126, in import_module
>      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>   ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See >https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
>
> for some common reasons and solutions. Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this error during my setup.  But my environment is Windows 7.
Uninstalled the Python and reinstalled python 3.5 and continued the setup.
Next followed this link to resolve the DLL load failed error: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup#pip_installation_on_windows

Comment: thanks for the heads up. Unfortunately I tried that as well.
Also, just to check that that dll is part of my path, if I open a command prompt and just type in MSVCP140.DLL, it pops up a window saying there is no program associated with it.

Comment: thanks for the update. Can you please do one more check, is your system has latest visual c++ redistribution package?